# Install git on Cent OS 5 EC2

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, installation, centos

I'm trying install git on new EC2 instance with CentOS release 5.11 (Final) using `sudo yum install git`  but got this error:

[image: error]

I too try do an update with `sudo yum update` and install command but the same error appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On centos you need to download and compile each git package which you will wish o use. (like: `git stash, git ...`)

Read this post on how to do it.
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-git-on-centos-5/

Set the git version to the latest version. If you do manage to install it via yum you will get the latest git version for CENTOS which is git 1.7.9

You can also try this :

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
sudo yum install git2u
```

Comment: you  have to update the version number. Updated script for you as well in the answer

Comment: got it! I tried do one more time the post tutorial with a different version, like you said, so a get the link of version 1.8.5.5 [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-core/downloads?page=1) instead of the link of tutorial and works fine.